# Connect to Azure Sql Database in Visual Studio Code using Active Directory Authentication

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-sql-database, database-connection, windows-authentication

I am looking to connect to azure sql server in Visual studio code using one of the Active Directory connection modes. However seems only sql authentication is supported as of now in visual studio code. Any help here is appreciated.

Tried checking in visual studio code documentation but didn't find any mention of active directory authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using Azure Data Studio, which is derived from VS Code for use with SQL Azure and other Azure Data services.  It supports Azure Active Directory authentication (which is a bit different than traditional integrated authentication against a local AD.  Given that SQL Azure isn't domain joined to your local domain, you would not be able to use it to authenticate anyways.

Here's the release notes where they mention AAD auth support[Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/release-notes-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Visual Studio Code has options that do not exist in Azure Data Studio, so it is not a complete replacement.  For example I can use VI key bindings in VS Code, but not in Data Studio.  This was checked as the correct answer but not given a up vote.  That might indicate some frustration with the answer by the OP.   However finding this answer by MSFT does let me know that I have come to the end of the road of the exact same journey.

Comment: It may be possible to connect VS Code directly to SQL, but the SQL team makes the Azure Data Studio based on VS Code specifically to enable scenarios like more complex auth models.  If you want to suggest features you need in Azure Data Studio, there is a path to do that.  If you want to suggest to VS Code (the team that builds this is in the developer division of Microsoft), I believe they have a separate forum for making suggestions.

Comment: Update:  Azure SQL DB Managed Instance (which is very similar but not the normal Azure SQL Database) went into preview with a feature to help with AD auth models.  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/mission-critical-app-modernization-made-easy-with-azure-sql/ba-p/2911495